# XML sheet names not seeming to agree with vba worksheet names

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large bloated workbook.

I've made the file a zip and opened the zip to inspect the xml files. Then I've looked at the worksheets folder in the zip to see this:

[image]

If I then look in the vba editor I can see this:

[image]

But "Sheet25" in the vba is a tab for notes with only 5 lines of text on it so these names are not the same.

Is there an easy way for me to map between the two different identifiers? e.g. what `Sheet` is `sheet25.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest check is to open `sheet25.xml`. You will see the matching codeName in this line at the top:

```
    <sheetPr codeName="Sheet22"/>
```

---

**EDIT**:

If you don't want to open the xml file (because it's too big), there is another way you can trace the mapping of the xml sheet filenames to the codeNames of the sheets in the workbook.

Open up the `xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels` document. You should see lines like this:

```
<Relationship Target="worksheets/sheet3.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Id="rId3"/>
<Relationship Target="worksheets/sheet2.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Id="rId2"/>
<Relationship Target="worksheets/sheet1.xml" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/worksheet" Id="rId1"/>
```

Link the xml sheet name to its resource ID on the far right, e.g.,

`worksheets/sheet2.xml` => `Id="rId2"`

Then open up the `xl/workbook.xml` document, where you get:

```
<sheet r:id="rId1" sheetId="1" name="one"/>
<sheet r:id="rId2" sheetId="3" name="Sheet3"/>
<sheet r:id="rId3" sheetId="4" name="Sheet1"/>
```

Link the resource ID to the sheet name, e.g.,

`r:id="rId2"` => `name="Sheet3"`

And then from the VBE editor:

```
Sheet3 (Sheet3)
```

Match the name to the tab name inside the parentheses to get the codeName:

`Sheet3` <= `(Sheet3)`

Done.

Comment: they are not the same - as I said "Sheet25" is the notes sheet with 5 lines of text - it definitely is not that size

Comment: @whytheq What do you see for the codeName when you open sheet25,xml ?

Comment: well part of me was hoping to not even have to open that file - can you see the size of it - hence the start of my question "Is there an easy way..."

Comment: @whytheq The only way to prove me wrong is by opening the file ;) Can notepad handle a file that big?

Comment: ok - notepad was quickish to open it "codeName="Sheet22": as I said they are not a direct mapping

Comment: @whytheq Yep. Should always trust the person who actually has the workbook in their hands over one who is speculating ;) Anyways, I worked out how to find out the mappings. Will update the answer.

Comment: @whytheq Updated answer with mapping instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the sheet number of the xml file is just the order of the sheet in the workbook counting from the left at the point at which you saved the file. To find it you can open your spreadsheet and unhide all sheets.  Alternatively you can use the formula =SHEET() in a worksheet to identify its number.

Note that this is different to the sheetcode in VBA which is a permanent sheet number that you see if you open the project explorer in VBA.  The sheetcode will not change if you move it around.